# Calculate Time Difference between time in text file and now

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, text-processing, strptime

I am new to Python and am writing a simple script to calculate the time difference between  a time written to a text file and now. The format of the time in the text file is: 2013-10-05 00:20

This is the script

```
f = open('N:\\newfile.txt')
timestamp = f.readline()
f.close()
now = str(datetime.now())
#Removing the seconds from the now time
now = now[0:16]
FMT = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'
tdelta = datetime.strptime(now, FMT) - datetime.strptime(timestamp, FMT)
print tdelta
```

But when I run it I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "N:\Test.py", line 12, in <module>
tdelta = datetime.strptime(now, FMT) - datetime.strptime(timestamp, FMT)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python26\lib\_strptime.py", line 328, in _strptime
data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains:
```

Can anyone please suggest what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `readline()` method of file objects returns a line *including it's terminating newline*. Python's documentation has [the details](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects):

> `f.readline()` reads a single line from the file; a newline character (`\n`) is left at the end of the string, and is only omitted on the last line of the file if the file doesn’t end in a newline. This makes the return value unambiguous; if `f.readline()` returns an empty string, the end of the file has been reached, while a blank line is represented by `'\n'`, a string containing only a single newline.

So, your `timestamp` looks something like this:

```
'2014-06-18 23:33\n'
```

... and `strptime()` is choking on that final newline. You can fix it by changing this line:

```
timestamp = f.readline()
```

to

```
timestamp = f.readline().strip()
```

(using the [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) method to strip whitespace from the string).

Answer (score 0):

If you are new with python I recommend to use `dateutil.parse` module, it lets to parse the common date formats, even if you don't know what it is using currently

Ex:

```
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>>
>>> utc_time = '2014-06-19T00:00:00'
>>> dateutil.parser.parse(utc_time)
datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 19, 0, 0)
>>> local_time = '2014-06-19 00:00:00+0002'
>>> dateutil.parser.parse(local_time)
datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 19, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 120))
>>> #even with new line char
>>> time_with_new_line = '2014-06-19 00:00\n'
>>> dateutil.parser.parse(time_with_new_line)
datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 19, 0, 0)
```

Once you parsed the string date to datetime object, the substract is trivial

```
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> with open('newfile.txt','r') as f:
...     datetime.now() - dateutil.parser.parse(f.readline())
... 
datetime.timedelta(0, 28100, 210498)
```

Comment: You are welcome, dateutil.parser works like a charm!